# Matplotlib fill_between() plot not always displayed in a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot

I often use fill_between() to represent the error on my time series plots and save them as pdf files (using plt.savefig()) which I then insert into either PowerPoint presentations, or MS Word files. I've personally never had any issues in seeing the plots. However, recently, a couple of instances occurred where others could not see the specific plots generated by the fill_between() function. The other plots in the figure were visible without issue.

I wonder if anybody else has had this issue, and any possible solution for this. Would saving as a .png file ensure that the shaded regions always show up?

Thanks

EDIT: The persons who cannot see the shaded regions due to fill_between() are anonymous reviewers of my research paper, hence its not possible to go communicate with them to investigate if the problem is in their systems or mine. Rather, my question is more generic and not situation-specific. Once a plot is saved (in this case, as a pdf), I didn't expect it to change.

An example of fill_between() in my code:

```
def plot(ts,err,Label,col,sty):
    plt.plot(ts.index,ts,col,linestyle=sty,linewidth=2, label=Label)
    plt.fill_between(ts.index,ts-err, ts+err
              , alpha=0.15, edgecolor=col, facecolor=col)

plot(dataTs,err(dataTs),'label','k','-')
plt.savefig('../Figures/test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Output plot:
[image]

The machine and the OS that I use: Macbook Pro, macOS Sierra.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example which does not show correctly. Also, one would need to know what systems the viewers have. Possibly the fault is on their side not on yours or matplotlibs. Chances that the image is presented in the same way as intended are indeed higher when using png.

Comment: Updated my question with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you used an alpha value in `fill_between`. While this should normally be fine, it seems some newer versions in MacOSs pdf viewer include a bug that lets semitransparent regions disappear when the pdf is included in Latex. Is this the case here? This is of course the Mac users problem, but to be on the save side, just set the colors to opaque and use a lighter grey (which is visually the same).

Comment: Thanks, good to know about the pdf-MacOS problem with semi-transparent regions. Then do you think saving to .png get rid of this issue? Your suggestion of using a lighter but opaque grey is good but I use several different colors in my plots.

Comment: I cannot guarantee that the issue is the one I think it is, but of course in this case, using png would probably resolve the issue, in case the journal accepts png images. You'd then also need to make sure the resolution is high enough not to end up with pixelated plots (`plt.savefig("filename.png", dpi=600)` or so).

Comment: Concerning the use of lighter colors: That would also work with different colors since there will always be an opaque color equivalent to the semitransparent one (one could e.g. find that out using a colorpicker program). The question is more whether the semitransparant regions overlap and thus whether you really need transparency to get the information in the plot accross.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough replies. I'll switch to high resolution .png. Good catch about lighter colors; Yes, the regions do overlap.

Comment: I had the same problem, my Chrome Browser did not display the shaded area correctly. I resolved it by **importing the PDF into Inkscape and saving it again as a PDF**.